# Is there any way of copying the contents(only files) of one directory WITHOUT iterating through all the files in that directory?

Tags: python, merge, filesystems

Is there any way of copying the contents(only files) of one directory to another directory WITHOUT iterating through all the files in the source directory?

I want to merge the contents of two folders containing millions of files. Iterating through all of them will take a lot of time.

Comment: The file system itself (at least, none that I am aware of) doesn't have a meta-entry for "all non-directory items" that you can use to copy the files *en masse*. You have to copy them one-by-one.

Comment: Iteration itself will be a trivial amount of time for millions of entries. Iterating over `range(10000000)` takes only 250 milliseconds on my machine.